# select qualified element from 2D array into a new list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array of integer value:

```
[[26, 9, 24, 13],
 [16, 14, 39, 29]]
```

I need to select the number >= 14, ends in 9 or 4, and not 39. It returns 1 if the criteria meets, otherwise return 0, i.e.

```
[[0, 0, 1,0],
 [0,0,0,1]]
```

updated: code suggested by Tomothy32

```
result = result = [[int(x >= 14 and x % 10 in (4, 9) and x != 19) for x in sl] for sl in X]
```

another nested loop approach

```
def test(X):
    out = [[0]*len(X[0]) for _ in range(len(X))]
    for i in range(len(X)):
        for j in range(len(X[i])):
            check = X[i][j]
            if check>=14 and check%5==4 and check!=39:
                out[i][j] = 2
    return out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
x = [[26, 9, 43, 13],
     [16, 14, 39, 29]]
result = [[int(x >= 14 and x % 10 == 9 and x != 39) for x in sl] for sl in x]
print(result)
# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

To get the last digit, use the remainder/modulo operator.

Comment: Thanks. what if I want to add an OR condition (or ends in 4).....result = [[int(x >= 14 and (x % 10 == 9 or x % 10 == 4) and x != 19) for x in X] for x in X]?

Comment: @user11417909 That should work, or you can use the condition `x >= 14 and x % 10 in (4, 9) and x != 39`.

Comment: @user11417909 The issue is that you are using the same names for your variables. Look at my example: I use `x` and `sl` for the number and the sublist, respectively.

Comment: it works now. But the testing expects a faster coding (15 times faster than nested loop...) any other idea?

Comment: @user11417909 What kind of "testing"? On a website or something?

Comment: compare with a nested loop method...pls see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

Change this statements:

```
if element >=14 and element !=39:
```

to

```
if element >=14 and element !=39 and element%10==9:
```